# How to update textview in android with an update in a value of a particular key of a Parse Object?

Tags: android, parse-platform, textview

Say I have two `Users`. Each `user` has a common `ParseObject` of which they can access and update particular `value` (associated to them) of a `key`. My question is if the first user updates the `value` of that `key`, What is the best way to get that`value` updated on the `Textview` of second user's android layout.

The ideas that strike me are

1. Using a timer and updating the `Textview` periodically.
2. Using an `IntentService` for the android activity and listen for the updates.

I think this put lot's of work on my application because the update of the `value` is expected in random intervals.

Is there any better solution to solve this ?